# Inject a field in Abstract Class using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an abstract class, which has many classes extending it. The abstract class has a field used by all the child classes. The field needs to be injected using guice.

```
   public abstract class StrategyClass {
      @Inject
      ClassTobeInjected variableName;
  }
```

I have a provider written for injecting this, which has a provider and a singleton:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        final AppConfigBinder appConfigBinder = new AppConfigBinder(binder());
        appConfigBinder.bindPrefix("*");
   }
   @Provider
   @Singleton
   public ClassTobeInjected getfield() {
      return new Instance of ClassTobeInjected;
   }
}
```

I see that the provider is creating an instance. However the abstract class field is always null. Do I need to add anything in the configure of my module? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Please explain how your StrategyClass is extended.

Comment: The strategy class is a base class for multiple validators. Each validator is used at multiple places. Now, it is not possible to inject the variables in those classes which are using the child classes of strategy class, since it needs to be used by all the child classes.

Comment: The content of the problem is not enough to provide a solution. There can be multiple ways to solve depending on the issue. Your issue seems more generic. See if you can update more on it.

Comment: You need to use constructor injection, passing the parent properties up through `super()` in order to do this.